# How to add custom ID for Celery task in order to revoke task later?

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to create delayed task and if there would be some conditions, I need to find that task and revoke it.

This is how I create task:

```
notify_before_departure.apply_async(
            args=(user.fcm_registration_token, booking.bus_stop_from.title,),
            eta=notification_time,
        )
```

So is there any attribute `apply_async` has where I can define my custom ID which can later be used to revoke this exact task? Something like this:

```
# create task
notify_before_departure.apply_async(
                args=(user.fcm_registration_token, booking.bus_stop_from.title,),
                eta=notification_time,
                custom_id=booking.id
            )
# revoke if needed
from celery.task.control import revoke 
revoke(booking.id, terminate=True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, answering my own question after reading [FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-specify-a-custom-task-id) :

```
notify_before_departure.apply_async(
            args=(user.fcm_registration_token, booking.bus_stop_from.title,),
            eta=notification_time,
            task_id=f"departure_push_for_booking_{booking.id}"
        )
```

And then:

```
revoke(f"departure_push_for_booking_{booking.id}", terminate=True)
```

---